# ASN1 CHOICE with only one entry, what does this mean?

Tags: asn.1

I'm looking at a schema that has this (parameter names changed).

```
config-1 CHOICE {
   value-1  INTEGER(1..40)
}
```

What does this mean?  What good is a CHOICE with only one possible thing to choose from?  Does this mean that `value-1` is optional?

Comment: It seems redundant to me, but perhaps they’re thinking of future proofing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way this makes sense for me is if your specification has EXTENSIBILITY IMPLIED

Your CHOICE would automatically get the extension marker and could be extended in the future

```
config-1 CHOICE {
   value-1  INTEGER(1..40),
   ...,
   [[
      value-2 IA5String
   ]]
}
```

This also means that if you decode config-1 and receive something else than value-1 you should not raise an error